# NSString Memory Warning in objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
    NSString * str1 = nil;
    NSString * str2 = nil;
    str1 = @"";
    str2 = @"";
```

I got memory warning **"Value stored to 'str1' is never read"** on above statement.
 Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: What kind of warning? Can you put the warning message in your question?

Comment: Value stored to 'str1' is never read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning:

```
Value stored to 'str1' is never read
```

is simply telling you that you have a variable which you set and never use. You'll see the same sort of thing with:

```
static void xyzzy (void) {
    int plugh = 7;
}
```

where clearly the `plugh` variable is not being used.

That's not a serious problem (otherwise it would be an error rather than a warning) but it does notify you that either:

- you're wasting space (and possibly time if you're setting it); or
- it may be indicative of another problem.

One example of the latter is if you are accidentally using `str2` somewhere where you intended to use `str1` (possibly due to a cut-and-paste where you forgot to change the pasted code).

As to how to fix it:

- If you're really not using it (and have no intention of using it), just get rid of it.
- If you *are* going to use it, commenting it out temporarily will get rid of the warning until you do.
- If you think you *should* be using it, then you have a problem elsewhere and you should track that down.